# PhP Codeigniter with mogodb and mysql

Tags: mysql, mongodb, codeigniter

Can anyone assist in pointing me how to use MongoDB and MySQL databases for building an ecommerce website with codeigniter PHP.

Comment: i'm wondering how you found SO ;) because first google hit was https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Using-MongoDB-in-Codeigniter - maybe you gv this a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under configuration.php, you might want to do the following:

```
$db['mysql']['hostname'] = "server";    #your data source
$db['mysql']['username'] = "username";  #user credentials
$db['mysql']['password'] = "p@ssword";  #user credentials
$db['mysql']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";

$db['mongodb']['hostname'] = "server";  #your data source
$db['mongodb']['username'] = "username";  #user credentials
$db['mongodb']['password'] = "p@assword";
$db['mongodb']['dbdriver'] = "mongodb";
```

Comment: did you test this ? .... https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/tree/develop/system/database/drivers i dont see a mongodb driver there.

Comment: no you did not - you didn't install a mongodb and you didn't try out the driver because - in CI there is no mongodb driver ....if you would've tested it you would see a message `Invalid DB driver`

Comment: ow. that's nice. i must have been mistaken. yes?